# pyqt + core.interact start endless loop

Tags: python, qt, interactive

I was trying to give the user of a pyqt software of mine direct acess to the python programming language so that he could manipulate the software from inside (on his own risk)

I try to use `code.interact` but it entered an infinity loop printing `QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running`. Executing just `code.interact` works and the software in PyQt4 also works. It is prety much clear that code.interact is somehow trying to start a Qt aplication and falling because there is one already working.

I wounder if anyone has a work around beside implementing the exec loop for my self. Here is a code example, WARNING: it enters a loop and there no way of stoping it beside killing (so save everything you are doing).

```
# DANGER: infinite loop
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import code

class ConsoleStarter(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConsoleStarter, self).__init__()
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Start Interactive Console")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.code)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button, 0,0)
        self.show()
    def code(self):
        code.interact()


app = QtGui.QApplication([])
console = ConsoleStarter()

app.exec_()
```

P.S. I'm running Debian Jessie with KDE

Comment: I tried to move `code.interact()` in separate thread and it works.

Comment: In fact a good idea, thank you.